# Multiply two matrices in Julia

Tags: julia

I have this code and I want to run it but I got some error, I think It's about type of my data but I can't understand how should I write it for preventing it.

```
function dacmm(i0::Int64, i1::Int64, j0::Int64, j1::Int64,
        k0::Int64, k1::Int64, A::Int64, B::Int64, c::Int64, n::Int64, basecase::Int64)
## A, B, C are matrices
## We compute C = A * B
    if n > basecase
        n = n/2
        dacmm(i0, i1, j0, j1, k0, k1, A, B, c, n, basecase)
        dacmm(i0, i1, j0, j1+n, k0, k1+n, A, B, c, n, basecase)
        dacmm(i0+n, i1, j0, j1, k0+n, k1, A, B, c, n, basecase)
        dacmm(i0+n, i1, j0, j1+n, k0+n, k1+n, A, B, c, n, basecase)
        dacmm(i0, i1+n, j0+n, j1, k0, k1, A, B, C, n, basecase)
        dacmm(i0, i1+n, j0+n, j1+n, k0, k1+n, A, B, c, n, basecase)
        dacmm(i0+n, i1+n, j0+n, j1, k0+n, k1, A, B, c, n, basecase)
        dacmm(i0+n, i1+n, j0+n, j1+n, k0+n, k1+n, A, B, c, n, basecase)
    else
        for i= 1:n, j=1:n, k=1:n
            c[i+k0,k1+j] = c[i+k0,k1+j] + A[i+i0,i1+k] * B[k+j0,j1+j]
        end
    end
end

n=4;
basecase = 2;
A = [rem(rand(Int32),5) for i =1:n, j = 1:n];
B = [rem(rand(Int32),5) for i =1:n, j = 1:n];
C = zeros(Int32,n,n);
```

error:
ArgumentError: invalid index: 1.0

```
Stacktrace:
 [1] to_indices at ./indices.jl:215 [inlined]
 [2] to_indices at ./indices.jl:213 [inlined]
 [3] getindex at ./abstractarray.jl:882 [inlined]
 [4] dacmm(::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Array{Int64,2}, ::Array{Int64,2}, ::Array{Int32,2}, ::Float64, ::Int64) at ./In[24]:16
 [5] dacmm(::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Array{Int64,2}, ::Array{Int64,2}, ::Array{Int32,2}, ::Int64, ::Int64) at ./In[24]:6
 [6] include_string(::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:515
```

Comment: I think the amount of help that can be offered here is limited, because your code doesn't really make sense. For starters, you assert that `## A, B, C are matrices`, but your function signature states `A::Int64, B::Int64, c::Int64`. Nonetheless, you are indeed treating `A`, `B`, and `c` as matrices in your `for` loop... Also, the function modifies the input `c`, so it would be customary to write the signature `dacmm!`, just so others are aware the inputs are modified.

Comment: Yes, that is a classical issue for newcomers from other scientific programming languages, such as R or Matlab, who don't have the concept of scalars. An `Int64` explicitly means a scalar. A matrix of Ints is called `Matrix{Int64}`. But in fact there is no reason to specify the types of all the input arguments, unless you want to define multiple methods that change behaviour by the type of input arguments.

Comment: I think `n/2` gives a float but you specify Int for it.

Comment: what daycaster said. The division operation returns float by default, even on integer arguments, so it cannot be used as an index. You can use `div` (also `÷`) for integer division instead.

Comment: Until you really need the speed, it may be better to keep your arguments to `dacmm` untyped. If `A`, `B`, and `C` are all of type `Matrix{Int64}`, then Julia will automatically compile `dacmm` to work with that set of arguments. Also, pay close attention to the comments from @daycaster and Tasos  about integer v. floating point numbers; that is a common performance gotcha in Julia.

Comment: There is no speed penalty to leaving function arguments untyped. you only need the types if you want to dispatch different methods.

Answer (score 1):

As the stack trace points out, you tried to call a method of the `dacmm` function which takes a Float64 in the penultimate argument:

`|
                                  V
[4] dacmm(::Int64, ::Int64, ... ::Float64, ::Int64) at ./In[24]:16
[5] dacmm(::Int64, ::Int64, ... ::Int64,   ::Int64) at ./In[24]:6`

but no such method is available. You ended up there because `n = n/2` returned a float not an integer.

The problem doesn't occur in the [original code](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno/cs2101a_moreno/htmls/labs/answer_lab4.pdf) because there, the function's arguments weren't too restricted with type information.